# Reassigning labels using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Each `ID` records a series of signal label: `"alpha"`, `"beta"` and `"unknown"`.
If an ID has only two labels. Then I wish to assign the dominating label to all i.e. if the recorded labels of an ID is
`c("alpha", "alpha", "unknown")`, it becomes `c("alpha", "alpha", "alpha")`

Can someone please help me with this.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data preparation (you can directly work with the tbl below)
ID <- c(rep("A", 14), rep("B", 14), rep("C", 10), rep("D", 22), rep("E", 2))
series <- c(11, 3, 12, 2, 8, 2, 11, 8, 3, 2)

label <- unlist(
  sapply(series, function(x) {case_when(x < 5 ~ rep("unknown", x),
                                            x >= 5 ~ case_when(x > 10 ~ rep("alpha", x),
                                                               x <= 10 ~ rep("beta", x))                                                               )
  }))

# tbl
tbl <- tibble(ID = ID, 
              label = label)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, from this

```
tbl %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n_distinct(label))
1 A                       2
2 B                       2
3 C                       2
4 D                       3
5 E                       1
```

We want to update labels for IDs `A`, `B` and `C` but not `D` or `E`. We can make use of the table function to get the most occurring within those IDS.

```
tbl2 <- tbl %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(label = if(n_distinct(label) == 2) names(which.max(table(label))) else label)
```

Which now gives the number of distinct labels per ID

```
tbl2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(n_distinct(label))
  ID    `n_distinct(label)`
  <chr>               <int>
1 A                       1
2 B                       1
3 C                       1
4 D                       3
5 E                       1
```

Comment: Thanks that it correct. Also is there a way to do it with just dplyr.

Comment: @SiH I don't think there is a native way in `dplyr` to make frequency tables and subset based on that (although there *should be*). A possible approach that only uses `dplyr` could be  a dynamic `case_when` or `slice_max(1)`, both of which don't make for pretty code (I haven't found anything less than 5 additional function calls yet).  `nest_by(ID)` combined with a `purrr::map` might be an alternative.